# Alternatives to JMegahal

Tags: machine-learning, java

I'm looking for an alternative to [JMegahal](http://www.jibble.org/jmegahal/) that is just as simple, and easy to use, but yields better results. I know JMegahal uses Markov chains to generate new strings, and I know that they're not necessarily the best. I was pointed towards Bayesian Network as the best conceptual solution to this problem, but I cannot find any libraries for Java that are easy to use at all. I saw WEKA, but it seemed bloated, and hard to follow. I also saw JavaBayes, but it was almost completely undocumented (their javadocs contained little to no information, and the variables were poorly named) and the library was blatantly written in C-style, making it stand out in Java.

Comment: You should embrace native code, don't reject it based on the differences in coding style; it's written in a different way because it's a different language.

Comment: I don't reject native code, I reject the idea of Java libraries that are written in the style of C. I believe it best to stick to the style guide purported by each language. I also wasn't aware that EBayes was wrapping native functions, though you're seemingly implying it, as it gives no such indication. Regardless, it's poorly documented.

Comment: I simply misread your post, you're saying that they wrote java code in C-style. I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider extending JMegahal to filter the input sentences. Back in the mid-90s, Jason Hutchens had written a C version of this 4th-order Markov strings algorithm (it was probably used as inspiration for the JMegahal implementation actually). At that time, Jason has added filters to improve on the implementations (by replacing 'you' by 'I', etc...). By doing some basic string manipulation meant to change the subject from the speaker to the system, the output became a lot more coherent. I think the expanded program was called HeX.

[Reference 1](http://megahal.alioth.debian.org/How.html)

[Reference 2](http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~cfs/472_html/Intro/NYT_Intro/History/MachineIntelligence1.html)

Comment: Beyond replacing you with I and things of that sort, what other substitutions, and filters would you recommend?

Comment: It really depends what you are using statistical language learning for. If you want to build some chatbot, you have to make substitutions that will project what the users say into what the bot should have said (hence the pronoun substitutions and that sort of things). If you are trying to build a natural language recognizer/processor, then you need to try to normalize the words (i.e. synonyms, infinitive forms, etc...) so the HMM weights are distributed according to meaning, not the choice of words.

Comment: the statistical language learning is going towards an IRC bot, so, it falls into the realm of chatbots. So, along the lines of pronoun substitutions, what other sort of things should I be looking for? I want to make sure that it's at least a bit comprehensive, as current experiences have led to less than satisfactory results at most times.